# Correlation coefficient for transformation of variables $Y=gS+T$

Tags: correlation

I have a random variable $Y$ which is related to another random variable $S$ by the relation $Y=gS+t$, where $g$ and $t$ are constants.

Let $X$ be another random variable. Then it is claimed that $\rho_{YX}=g\frac{\sigma_S}{\sigma_Y}\rho_{SX}$.

Can anyone please help me understand how this expression is true, or refer me to relevant literature? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand this you need to understand the properties of the variance for a random variable $S$ with $Variance(S)=\sigma^2_S$ and standard deviation $\sigma_S$.
Then, assuming $g,t$ being two constants the random variable $Y= gS+t$ has variance $Variance(Y)= g^2Variance(S)=g^2\sigma^2_S$. The $t$ disappears because the variance is invariant of shifts of the distribution and you can get this result by writing down the formula for the variance of $Y$. Besides, I would not use a capital letter for a constant because it's easy to confuse with the notation for a random variable, so I wrote $t$ in place of $T$.

Assuming the correlation coefficient $\rho_{X,Y}= \frac{Covariance(X,Y)}{\sqrt{Var(X)}\sqrt{Var(Y)}}$, now you can try to derive the equality in your question.

If you can't manage, I'll write down the full derivation but if I was you I would give it a try first ;)

One more hint: $Covariance(X,Y)=Covariance(X,gS+t)=gCovariance(X,S)$.

As a reference, look at the Wikipedia page ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance)) under the section Propagation and you will find some derivations of these formulas.

Comment: Thank you! The mistake I made was that $T$ is not a constant, but a sum of random variables $\sum_{i=1}^{n} t_i$. These being independence of $S$, your covariance expression works. The variance is now $V(Y)=g^2V(S)+\sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_{ti}^2$, which gives me my required expression!